# Power function versus p-value for a normal test of means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, statistical-power

In my lecture notes, the power function under a test with rejection region $R$ is defined as: $ \beta(\theta) = P_{\theta} ((X_1 ,..., X_n) \in R) $ and the p-value is defined as $ p = inf(\alpha $ : the level$-\alpha$ test rejects $H_0$ based on sample $\bar X$). I also understand that the p-value is the probability of an observation atleast as extreme as the observation occuring under the null hypothesis.

I exercised these definitions on the tests for normal means (variance known) i.e:

$ H_0: \mu = \mu_0 $ and $ H_1: \mu \neq \mu_0 $

The power function came out to be:

$ \beta(\mu) = 1 - \Phi(Z_{\alpha/2} - \frac{\mu - \mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}) +  \Phi(- Z_{\alpha/2} - \frac{\mu - \mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}) $

I am, however, confused about how to figure out the p-value of this particular sense. The definition as per the notes seems to be a far cry from my understanding, and if I followed the more intuitive definition it turns out to be :

$ p = P( |\bar{X} - \mu_0| > Z_{\alpha/2}.\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}) $

But isn't this exactly the power function? Is it allowed, or have I misunderstood either of the definitions?